# Is there any problems in mysql5.1 server with mysql5.0 client?

Tags: mysql, mysql5

We are going to replace DB servers with mysql5.1.

Our dba team recommend that using mysql5.0 client

because, they have enough skill and know-how with mysql5.0 client.

Is there any problems in mysql5.1 server  with mysql5.0 client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended would be normally to run client and server using the same major version of MySQL.

Other than that I don't really think it would be a major problem to connect a 5.0 client to a 5.1 server, it would be a much bigger problem the other way around, but be aware that your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thank you in advance , Did you mean that 5.1 svr with 5.0 client has no major problem . but your recommendation is 5.1 with 5.1 . I'd like to recommend to DBA manager 5.1 with 5.1 . How can I say something good ?

Comment: Of course! 5.1 to 5.1 will always take full potential of the new features implemented in 5.1 server which the 5.0 client do not necessarily support. Also 5.1 client is completely backwards compatible with 5.0 and 4.1 which makes the update not problematic.

Comment: I see . Does anyone have the